# How to use rand function within for loop to generate different numbers to store within variable x, without recompiling

Tags: c++, random

i'm a new c++ programmer converted from python as i want to extend my knowledge base.

basically, i want to generate a random number between 0 and 2, and store as variable difficulty range. then index difficulty ranges by that random number and store result as variable x. when i compile, the resulting output is 10, no matter how many times i recompile, the result is always 10. there is probably an easy solution and/or im using the rand() function incorrectly. i want the output of x to change without having to recompile the code later as well, please let me know if that is at all possible, and any changes i can make to my code to make it run more efficiently. its probably an easy fix but i simply do not know enough of the language to see my mistakes as i am self taught :)

sample code from my problem:

```
int difficulty_ranges[3] = {10,50,100};
for(int difficulty_range = 0; difficulty_range < 3; difficulty_range = rand() % 2 + 1){
    int x = difficulty_ranges[difficulty_range];
    std::cout << x;
    break;
};
```

}

output:
10

Comment: read documentation of funcitons you are using. It should mention how to seed the generator via `srand()`

Comment: Don't use `rand` in 2024. Use the C++ infrastructure for generating random numbers instead.

Comment: Your loop is wrong. You initialise `difficulty_range` to `0`, so it will always be `0` on the first iteration. And you `break` in the first iteration, so `rand` is never called.

Comment: i dont understand why there is a loop in the first place. I think you just want to get a radnom number in [0,3), use that as index to the array, store the element. No loop needed

Comment: @Botje -- sure; when someone doesn't understand how to do something, recommend a more complex approach. After all, it's 2024. <g>

Comment: If they come from Python there's a good chance they were looking for something like `random.randint`, which is exactly what [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) provides. OP got the "generate random number" bit correct but messed up after that.